# DrRacket: How can I store an "equality detector" in a compound variable?

Tags: oop, lisp

Please change the title to something more appropriate if you wish.

I am making something in the form of an object-oriented program, there is a compound called `world` as defined here:

```
(define-struct world (var1 var2 var3 loo))
```

Where "var" 1 through 3 are `Number` and represent some worldly variables like temperature, humidity etc. `loo` is short for "list of objects", objects are defined below:

```
(define-struct obj (id act))
```

Where `id`is `Integer` and is the ID of the object, and `act` is yet another compound:

```
(define-struct act (trigger command))
```

Where `trigger` will be explained later and `command` is a `String`, representing a command that will be resolved in other parts of the program.

Here is my problem: I want `trigger` to be a expression that returns `true` if some variables of the world are in a certan way, for example, I want to make it so that when `var1` and `var2` have the same value, the command `"start-rain"` be issued. An "imgainary" piece of code for this will look like this:

```
(define (get-commands loo0)
   (local [(define (fn-for-loo todo rsf)
              (cond [(empty? todo) rsf]
                    [else (fn-for-obj (first todo)
                                      (rest todo)
                                      rsf)]))

           (define (fn-for-obj obj todo rsf)
              (if (true? (act-trigger (obj-act obj)))
                  (fn-for-loo todo (cons (act-command (obj-act obj)) rsf))
                  (fn-for-loo todo rsf)))]
      (fn-for-loo loo0 empty)))
```

In case that was hard to follow, an annotated version is here:

```
(define (get-commands loo0) ;;-------------------------------------------------This function returns (listof String), it uses local for tail-recursion
   (local [(define (fn-for-loo todo rsf) ;;------------------------------------rsf is result-so-far accumulator, it is (listof String)
              (cond [(empty? todo) rsf] ;;-------------------------------------rsf returned as final output of entire function when all objects are checked
                    [else (fn-for-obj (first todo) ;;--------------------------if some objects are unchecked, pass objects to fn-for-obj to check the first
                                      (rest todo)
                                      rsf)]))

           (define (fn-for-obj obj todo rsf) ;;--------------------------------receiving one object of attention, other unchecked object and result-so-far
              (if (true? (act-trigger (obj-act obj))) ;;-----------------------if the trigger returns true...
                  (fn-for-loo todo (cons (act-command (obj-act obj)) rsf)) ;;--add current object's command to the list of commands and pass on to fn-for-loo
                  (fn-for-loo todo rsf)))] ;;----------------------------------if trigger returns false, pass on without modification to rsf
      (fn-for-loo loo0 empty))) ;;---------------------------------------------this kick-starts the local functions
```

My problem is that I dont know what `trigger` should be, it must be something that returns a `Boolean` depending on variables in the `world`. Of course, the variables of the world will be accessible either by lexical scoping or direct reference, but how can I write the expression of `trigger` in `object` and before the program knows that the world variables will be available?

I am trying something like this:

```
(define OBJ1 (make-obj 1
                       (make-act (= var1 var2) "start-rain")))
```

but the compiler says "var1 is not defined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access parts of the world, you need to pass the world along:

```
(define (get-commands w loo0)
   (local [(define (fn-for-loo todo rsf)
              (cond [(empty? todo) rsf]
                    [else (fn-for-obj (first todo)
                                      (rest todo)
                                      rsf)]))

           (define (fn-for-obj obj todo rsf)
              (if ((act-trigger (obj-act obj)) w)
                  (fn-for-loo todo (cons (act-command (obj-act obj)) rsf))
                  (fn-for-loo todo rsf)))]
      (fn-for-loo loo0 empty)))

(define OBJ1
  (make-obj 1
            (make-act (lambda (w) (= (world-var1 w) (world-var2 w)))
                      "start-rain")))

(define OBJ2
  (make-obj 2
            (make-act (lambda (w) (= (world-var1 w) (world-var3 w)))
                      "go-home")))
```

(The `true?` predicate isn't very useful.)

Test:

```
(define w0 (make-world 1 1 1 (list OBJ1 OBJ2)))

> (get-commands w0 (world-loo w0))
'("go-home" "start-rain")
```

Many would prefer to use standard higher-order functions:

```
(define (get-commands w loo0)
  (foldl (lambda (o rs) (if ((act-trigger (obj-act o)) w)
                            (cons (act-command (obj-act o)) rs)
                            rs))
         '()
         loo0))
```

Note that your code produces the commands in the reverse order of the objects in the list.

If you want them in the same order, you can do this:

```
(define (get-commands w loo0)
  (foldr (lambda (o rs) (if ((act-trigger (obj-act o)) w)
                            (cons (act-command (obj-act o)) rs)
                            rs))
         '()
         loo0))
```

or this:

```
(define (get-commands w loo0)
  (let ((triggered (filter (lambda (o) ((act-trigger (obj-act o)) w)) loo0)))
    (map (lambda (o) (act-command (obj-act o))) triggered)))
```